# İnstall Linux server in 13TB hard disk

Tags: linux, centos, raid

Hi i have a server which has a 13TB hard disk with Raid 5.
My problem is when i try to install CentOs  it sees only 2TB of disk.
How can i use parted insted of fdisk in install process?
Or if you have any other solution i'am

Comment: Which version of CentOS?

Comment: Centos 6.2 64bit.

Comment: Unless your machine support EFI (instead of BIOS) you wont be able to boot from a drive larger than 2.2TB. If you do have EFI, make sure your RAID HBA's firmware is completely up to date. Also, what RAID HBA are you using?

Comment: Thanks Chris, we use one of intel raid card but not sure its model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to make a RAID 5 partition of this size...unless you do not care about the data or may loose the data and do not care.  Upon the loss of a disk in this system, it is likely you would encounter another unrecoverable error which would prevent the RAID from rebuilding correctly.  You might want to do a search for problems with RAID 5 and array of this size.  If I recall correctly, you may not even want a RAID 6 for such a device.